# Determine the cycle duration of an animated GIF in javascript

Tags: javascript, gif

Is it possible to determine the length of a GIF (in ms) using only Javascript? For example, if I'm viewing https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyngm.jpg and I want to determine how long the GIF loops for.

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gif-frames

Comment: The information is there, you just have to read it out of the source. Not quite sure what you mean by "using only Javascript". There are [JS packages out there](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=js+get+info+about+gif&oq=js+get+info+about+gif&aqs=chrome..69i57.2391j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you can use to find this date, or you can get it manually. Read [through this](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/gif-info/blob/master/index.js#L66) to get a feel for it